# Can you target multiple opponents in an Intrigue?

Tags: social-combat, song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg

When running an intrigue if there are 3 or more participants, could one person affect multiple people with a single roll if he addressed his remark to both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, according to the rules, but...

Looking through Chapter 8, at page 142, I found the following paragraph that covers the option of having multiple participants in an Intrigue:

> Most intrigues are between two characters at a time, though multiple intrigues can occur simultaneously between multiple pairs. When a character addresses a large audience, that audience usually looks to a leader to represent their interests, so even though there are numerous individuals involved, the intrigue can be settled between two opponents. On the other hand, an intrigue may feature participants who are supported by allies and advisors. Such periphery characters can modify the intrigue’s outcome by encouraging or mollifying the primary negotiator—bolstering his resolve or deflecting the influence of his opponent.

Generally, an Intrigue can have two sides, not more. But you can House Rule it to fit your needings, or splitting up the participants in more than one Intrigue.